# How can I change onClick function via if/else statement?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to have an image that changes to another when the user clicks a button. I achieved that goal, but I also need it to switch back to the first image when the button is clicked again. I have been unable to do so. I have posted my work below.

I would have thought that if/else statements would have done the trick, but my second click doesn't do anything.

```
public  class word1 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnClick;
ImageView image;
int pooter = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_word1);

btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttcard1);
image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCard1);
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(pooter % 2 == 0){
            pooter = +1;
            image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.an));
        }else{
            pooter = +1;
            image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.did));
        }
    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: `pooter = +1;` ... that's not how to increase the value. You can do `pooter++;` or `pooter = pooter + 1;` or `pooter += 1;`

Comment: Thanks that worked. I suppose I misinterpreted something that came up in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a field called `mIsFirstTime` and set its initial value to **true** in your activity like below.

```
private boolean mIsFirstTime=true;
```

Then use it as below  in your **Button onClick**

```
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(mIsFirstTime){

                image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.an));
                mIsFirstTime=false;
            }else{

                image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.did));
                mIsFirsTime=true;
            }
    }
  }
```

Of course as others said your problem will be solved if you **replace**  `poster=+1;` with `poster+=1;` or `poster++;`

But Using boolean condition is much **better and simpler** than using **even numbers condition**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use boolean. I'm definitely going to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(pooter % 2 == 0){
        pooter += 1;
        image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.an));
    }else{
        pooter += 1;
        image.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.did));
    }
```

would work as Paul said.